# Connect raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu server to wifi

Tags: networking, server, wireless, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4.

As I do not have a screen and keyboard available, I connect it through an Ethernet cable.

I want the Raspberry Pi to be connected to the Wi-Fi and not via Ethernet.

I tried to update `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-essid MYESSID12345
wpa-psk MYPASSWORD$1234567
```

Then I am running:

```bsh
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

But it does not seem to work.

`ifconfig` returns:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.41  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe62:c4fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:62:c4:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118  bytes 13529 (13.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 52  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63  bytes 9012 (9.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 168  bytes 12300 (12.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 168  bytes 12300 (12.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:62:c4:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I also tried to do it through:

```bsh
iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password
```

Or:

```bsh
iwconfig wlan0 essid name key s:password
```

But I have an invalid argument error because my password is 8 characters.

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I also tried `iwconfig wlan0 essid name` using wps but it does not work.

I also tried with `wpasupplicant`.

Creating `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` with

```
network={
    ssid="ssid_name"
    psk="password"
}
```

and then running `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext`

But I have errors too.

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works updating `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

Adding those lines to `network`

```
wifis:
    wlan0:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "SSID-NAME":
                password: "WIFI-PASSORD"
        dhcp4: true
```

Then

```
$ sudo netplan --debug try
$ sudo netplan --debug generate
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
```

and finally reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Is the `sudo reboot` step required at all?

Comment: I just tried this solution. After a reboot, still no connection but after a forced reconnected from my router all was fine. (PS. I have the Unify Dream Machine)

Answer (score 2):

I got headless Wi-Fi via Unbuntu 20.04 on RPi4B working without disabling cloud-init. In a 'nutshell' I used this for my network-config:

```
# This file contains a netplan-compatible configuration which cloud-init
# will apply on first-boot. Please refer to the cloud-init documentation and
# the netplan reference for full details:
#
# https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/
# https://netplan.io/reference
#

#Replace the entire user-data on the imaged SD Card with this file.

version: 2
renderer: networkd
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    dhcp6: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "SSID":
         password: "PassPhrase"
```

Then, I appended the following to the end of user-data:

```
power_state:
  mode: reboot
```

My config files, step-by-step, and notes are here: https://github.com/DavidUnboxed/Ubuntu-20.04-WiFi-RaspberyPi4B.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is recommended that the answers are not link only, and should describe in details the contents of the link.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

create `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` with

```
network={
    ssid="ssid_name"
    psk="password"
}
```

and run `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf && sudo dhclient wlan0` .

Or try to update `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid YOUR-SSID-HERE
    wpa-psk YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE
```

and reboot.